# Integrate steam authentication with front-end framework

Tags: node.js, vue.js, passport.js, openid, steam

I am currently developing an application with Node.js backend and vue.js as a frontend framework. As a log in for the application I am using passport-steam which works perfectly on the backend. A user is redirected to steam from the frontend in order to log in, the backend deals with the login and returns a req.user. Checking for user.isAuthenticated works on the backend. My question is how to pass that user information and the session that a user is authenticated to the frontend client ?

Server code:

```
    app.get('/auth/steam/return',
    passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/#/index');
    });

    app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.send({user: req.user});
    });
```

When the user is successfully authenticated with steam he is redirected to the frontend --> localhost:8080/#/index which creates an axios request to localhost:/3001/account the backend whith the information for the steam account. Unfortunately nothing happens as the frontend request is not authenticated. Any suggestions ?

Thanks a lot !!